# order by with dates from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

As an example, two tables:

- the first with posts (title and date of posts);
- the second with the comments of each post (title and date of comments)

**I want to list only the posts, ordered by date.**

The ordering must be done taking into account the dates of the posts and the dates of the comments.

The first post on the list is the one **with the most recent date of the post or comment**

EXAMPLE: Query with a LEFT JOIN, just to illustrate, since the goal is to list only the posts.

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN comments c ON p.id_post = c.id_post 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN c.comment_date > p.post_date 
THEN c.comment_date ELSE p.post_date END                                 
DESC
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Thanks, is mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery in the `order by`:

```
order by (select (case when max(c.comment_date) > p.post_date
                       then max(c.comment_date)
                       else p.post_date
                  end)
          from comments c
          where c.id_post = p.id_post
         ) DESC
```

Note:  Even if your database supports `GREATEST()`, it is not a good choice because it (usually) returns `NULL` if any argument is `NULL`.

If you want to do this with a `LEFT JOIN`, then you need to aggregate first:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT c.id_post, MAX(c.comment_date) as max_comment_date
      FROM comments c
      GROUP BY c.id_post
     ) c
     ON p.id_post = c.id_post 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN c.comment_date > p.post_date
               THEN c.comment_date ELSE p.post_date
          END) DESC;
```

In practice, I would expect for comments to appear only after the post, so this could be simplified to:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(c.comment_date, p.post_date)
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff

Comment: Hehehe, the number of time-travellers I've seen in databases ;)